# JPA or condition over oneToOne relations

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am working with JPA EclipseLink (Java and MySQL server) and I want to perform a query with a non exclusive or between some 'one to one' relations over the same atribute (primary key):

```
public class elements implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "element_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Element eFeatures1;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "element_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Element eFeatures2;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "element_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private NewCompoundsLM eFeatures3;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "element_id")
private int elementId;

... some more attributes
}

public class features1 implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "element_id")
private int elementId;

@Size(max = 20)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "kegg_id")
private String keggId;
... some more attributes
}

public class features2 implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "element_id")
private int elementId;

@Size(max = 20)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "hmdb_id")
private String hmdbId;
... some more attributes
}
... some more attributes
}

public class features3 implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "element_id")
private int elementId;
... some more attributes
}
```

Being element_id a foreign key in tables features1,features2 and features3

After that, I want to retrieve elements which are present in table eFeatures1 or eFeatures2 or eFeatures3, with a non exclusive or, but I do not get to perform it

I tried the next query:

```
SELECT e FROM elements e 
WHERE (e.features1.keggId!='' or e.features2.hmdbId!='') 
and (e.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and e.mass <= 236.0941826129821);
```

But, when I run that, I obtain the results which have e.efetarues1.keggId!='' **AND** e.efetarues2.hmdbId!='', being the result only one element. I want to retrieve the 3 elements that have e.efeatures1.keggId!='', the 3 elements that have e.efeatures2.hmdbId!='' and the 1 element that reach both conditions. 
Is there any way to obtain that with JPA EclipseLink?

I did in SQL, and I would like to perform this query in JPA:

```
SELECT c.compound_id,ck.kegg_id,ch.hmdb_id FROM compounds c 
LEFT JOIN compounds_kegg ck 
on c.compound_id=ck.compound_id 
left join compounds_hmdb ch 
on c.compound_id=ch.compound_id 
where (ck.kegg_id is not null or ch.hmdb_id is not null) 
and (c.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and c.mass <= 236.0941826129821);

+-------------+---------+-----------+
| compound_id | kegg_id | hmdb_id   |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|       50303 | NULL    | AAAA      |
|       68206 | NULL    | BBBB      |
|       89758 | AAAAAA  | NULL      |
|       95110 | BBBBBB  | NULL      |
|       91763 | CCCCCC  | NULL      |
|       71801 | DDDDDD  | EEEE      |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

but, when I run the query in JPA:

```
SELECT e FROM elements e 
WHERE (e.features1.keggId!='' or e.features2.hmdbId!='') 
and (e.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and e.mass <= 236.0941826129821);
```

the query only returns of 71801

Furthermore, when I run

```
SELECT e FROM elements e 
WHERE (e.ncKegg is not null or nc.ncHMDB is not null) 
and (nc.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and nc.mass <= 236.0941826129821)
```

the query returns all elements (8 elements instead of 6) which fulfill the last condition over the mass.

**EDITED:** I already did with query

```
SELECT c FROM NewCompounds c 
LEFT JOIN NewCompoundsKegg ck on c.compoundId=ck.compoundId 
LEFT JOIN NewCompoundsHMDB ch on c.compoundId=ch.compoundId 
where (ck.keggId is not null or ch.hmdbId is not null) 
and (c.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and c.mass <= 236.0941826129821)
```

But i do not get at all why I have to use left join in JPA if I already declared the relationships in the main element. Also, I do not know how it affects the performance of the application to include 3 left joins

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
SELECT c FROM NewCompounds c 
LEFT JOIN NewCompoundsKegg ck on c.compoundId=ck.compoundId 
LEFT JOIN NewCompoundsHMDB ch on c.compoundId=ch.compoundId 
where (ck.keggId is not null or ch.hmdbId is not null) 
and (c.mass >= 236.08001738701788 and c.mass <= 236.0941826129821)
```

But i do not get at all why I have to use left join in JPA if I already declared the relationships in the main element. Also, I do not know how it affects the performance of the application to include 3 left joins